# "addinter: The shared archive was not loaded "libtest_toolbox.so: undefined symbol: USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2"

Tags: c++, linux, scilab

While executing loader.sce commands in scilab I am getting following error:
exec loader.sce

--> // This file is released under the 3-clause BSD license. See COPYING-BSD.

--> // Generated by builder.sce: Please, do not edit this file

--> oldmode = mode();      mode(-1);
Start test_toolbox
    Load macros
    Load gateways
at line    15 of executed file /home/srkirve77/Desktop/code-files/Scilab6-Test-Toolbox-master/loader.sce

exec: error on line #16: "addinter: The shared archive was not loaded: /home/srkirve77/Desktop/code-files/Scilab6-Test-Toolbox-master/sci_gateway/cpp//libtest_toolbox.so: undefined symbol: USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2"

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question is lacking detail required for someone to provide a useful answer. I can vaguely guess that you've written a scilab toolbox but a related binary file hasn't been compiled with the required flags. But without a description of exactly what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it I can;t really tell.

Comment: Please give: version of Scilab, platform, OS, version of compilers installed, ...

Comment: Sorry for not giving details! I am using scilab version 6.1.0 , ubuntu 18.04,g++ -std=c++11